# How to print backslash in go?

Tags: go, printf, backslash, gofmt

I have the following code snippet:

```
const byte1 = 0x19;
const byte2 = 0x45;
msg := fmt.Sprintf("\\x%x\\x%x message", byte1, byte2)
log.Info("Learning go fmt", "msg", msg)
```

I get this:

```
msg="\\x19\\x45 message"
```

Why is the backslash duplicated? According to this [website](https://programming.guide/go/fmt-printf-reference-cheat-sheet.html), `\\` within a format should yield `\`.

Comment: you are using someother library to print the msg `log.Info` maybe it's un-escaping the string.

Comment: What @nilsocket said: https://play.golang.org/p/UQSK_MqYHma

Comment: Cheers @nilsocket, that was indeed the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@nilsocket's comment is correct. The problem is that I'm using the Ethereum [log](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/tree/master/log) package. It unescapes the string. If I do:

```
fmt.Println("\\x%x\\x%x message", byte1, byte2)
```

It works perfectly fine.